# How to Preload with Gorm in nested Struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

Here are the Struct relations:

```
    type A struct {
       Id int64 
       RelB []B `gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:Aid;ASSOCIATION_FOREIGNKEY:Id"`
    }
    type B strcut {
       Id int64
       Aid int64
       RelC []C `gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:Bid;ASSOCIATION_FOREIGNKEY:Id"`
    }
    type C struct {
       Id int64
       Bid int64
       RelD []D `gorm:"FOREIGNKEY:Cid;ASSOCIATION_FOREIGNKEY:Id"`
    }
    type D struct {
       Id int64
       Cid int64
    }
```

I try to find all of these relations with Preload like this:

```
var result []A    
db.Preload("RelB").Preload("RelB.RelC"). // if only three structs relations it works fine so far
Preload("RelB.RelC.RelD"). // it shows errors can not preload field RelD for A
Find(&result)
```

So, How to relate these four structs with preload? Or there is other better way?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `db.Preload("RelC.RelD")`? The docs are pretty terrible for gorm which is why I just switched to doing raw SQL, since stuff like this is a pain.

Comment: @Jesse  i had tried this. Calls the same error